# Splitting circular nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce the attached figure using the tikz package, but am having a hard time splitting the node with the {X,x} in it. Any suggestions?

[image: Taken from Richardson & Robins 2013]

Here's what I've come up with so far, but it's not good enough. The {X,x} node needs to be rotated and split, exactly as in the figure (colors not important):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [circle split,
         draw,
    line width = .05cm,
         minimum width=1cm,
         append after command={%
          let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.east)-(\tikzlastnode.west)$) in  
              node[draw,
                   shape=semicircle,
                   rotate=180,
                   anchor=south,
                   double,
                   minimum width=\x1] at (\tikzlastnode.center)     {}}]
  {$X$
    \nodepart{lower}
    $x$
  };
\node [ellipse,draw,line width=.05cm] at (3.75,0) {$Y(x)$};
\node [circle,draw,line width=.05cm] at (1.5,3) {$L$};
\node [circle,draw,line width=.05cm] at (4,4.5) {$H$};
\draw[->, line width=.125cm] (1.1,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw[->, line width=.125cm] (0.9,3) to [out=180,in=90]  (-.5,1);
\draw[->, line width=.125cm] (1.8,2.6) -- (3,.75);
\draw[->, line width=.125cm] (3.45,4.2) -- (2.1,3.25);
\draw[->, line width=.125cm] (4,3.9) -- (4,.85);
%\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,6) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using a rotated `semicircle` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\tikzset{
semi/.style={
  semicircle,
  draw,
  minimum size=2em
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.05cm]
\node [circle,draw] (h) {$H$};
\node [circle,draw,below left=1cm and 1.5cm of h] (l) {$L$};
\node [ellipse,draw,below=3.5cm of h] (y) {$Y(x)$};
\node[semi,left=2cm of y,shape border rotate=270] (x) {$x$};
\node[semi,left=0.3cm of x,shape border rotate=90] (X) {$X$};
\begin{scope}[line width=.125cm,shorten >= 5pt, shorten <= 5pt]
\draw[->] (x) -- (y);
\draw[->] (l) to [out=180,in=90]  (X);
\draw[->] (l) -- (y);
\draw[->] (h) -- (l);
\draw[->] (h) -- (y);
\end{scope}
%\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,6) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I used the `positioning` library to place the nodes, so you don't have to manually specify coordinates; I also used a `scope` with `shorten` options to draw the edges.